# How to add values to existing enum

Tags: swift, enums, alamofire

I use the Alamofire swift library to do some networking in my App.
I'm currently building my own ResponseSerializer.

According to Alamofire's docs you throw errors in the serialization process like this

```
let failureReason = "Data could not be serialized. Input data was nil."
let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
return .Failure(data, error)
```

So my thought was to use this method to throw some more errors not related to Alamofire that can appear in my serialization. For example if there is a problem on the server-side, the response includes an error description as a string.

I want to add some custom error codes like `.ServerErrorInJson` that I can use in the `errorWithCode(Alamofire.Error.Code, String) -> NSError` method.

Is there a way I can add those cases to the enum `Alamofire.Error.Code`?